# Firebase : Wait For Async and Push to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all data specified, and push to array, but this function return callback before the process is finish.

```js
function getRadiusPartner(){
      getAllPartner()
      .then(function (snap){
        var location = [];
        snap.forEach(function(user){
            coordsRef.child(user).once("value", function(snapshot){         
                location.push(snapshot.val());
            })  
        })
        return Promise.all(location)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally You cannot use .forEach() if you want to wait for a promise. 
Javascript and promises don't work in that way of knowing when the forEach will be done.

Now you do have a few options:

1. You can have a simple setTimeout function that waits a second or a little less and then fulfills the promise.

   ```
   function getRadiusPartner(){
    getAllPartner()
     .then(function (snap){
       var location = [];
       snap.forEach(function(user){
       coordsRef.child(user).once("value", function(snapshot){         
         location.push(snapshot.val());
       })  
      })
     setTimeout(function(){return Promise.all(location)},1500);
    });
   }
   ```
2. If you have an array you could have an if statement that checks if the loop is at Array.length - 1 and then resolve the promise
3. If you know what you are looking for you can return after you find the item in the foreach loop

   ```
    findItem = function (id) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    snap.forEach(items, function (item) {
    if (item.id === id) {
       defer.resolve(item);
     }
    });
   return defer.promise;
   };
   ```

Comment: thankyou.. if i want to use first option, how about if the data get more than 1500 ?

Comment: Well, the first option is a manual approach and not the most efficient, but it is the easiest to implement. A forEach loop is very very fast. If for some reason like internet being slow if pulling from online or something like that you can make the time a little longer just in case